# sudo pip: why, why not and alternatives

Tags: python, pip

Going around I read a lot about how `sudo pip` is a very bad habit/solution. Some reasons people gave were:

- It could run malicious code.
- It will break permission structs.
- Sudo is used to install a package "system wide".
- It is Satan!1!!one

An alternative I found is running `pip` with `--user` (e.g. `pip install --user package`). I saw that python in Debian works a little different (I have Stretch), mostly because of path used (`--user` is standard in Debian if omitted, btw). In conclusion, I found a lot of inconsistent things.

Taking for granted that using `sudo` and `pip` together are wrong, can someone explain me why, and most of all, **when** is it wrong? Major issues I encountered were all about permissions, so my guess is that `sudo` "just" ruin ownership.

Are there any other solutions besides using `--user` or virtualenv?

Comment: @Rawing if I had to guess, because this question has been asked and answered many times before, and a quick Google search reveals that.

Comment: Thanks for the edits! Anyway I already read the posts flagged as duplicated and they were the exact reason that pushed me to ask the question: in one post the answer is "because of ownership", in another is "because you run code from internet", another says "because of scope visibility"...

Comment: @vaultah Thanks, it seems my google-fu has failed me... I wasn't able to find any particularly useful information about this topic with a quick search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you *want* or *have* to install a binary, service or dependency globally, you would not want to use `sudo pip`.  As you surmise correctly, it installs your dependency globally, and this may cause inconsistencies while developing.

The more conventional thing to do nowadays is to use a [virtualenv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) with which to install your dependencies.  This way, anything you do with installation is local to that specific virtualenv instance of Python.

Comment: Tried to edit to correct spelling, but I would have to edit more than 6 characters.  Your link for `virtualenv` is mispelled.  Also, it is worth adding that to use a virtual environment, simply `source /path/to/my/venv/bin/activate` and then you can use pip to install most packages just as you normally would.

Comment: The location is correct, the letters aren't... you wrote `virutalenv` when it should be `virtualenv`